# Попятный или попятная?

Tags: значение-слов

"На попятный" (или "на попятную"?) бросаются те, кто хотят убежать, отступить. А что такое этот самый "попятный" и как все-таки правильно: "попятный" или "попятная"?
А еще всех девушек поздравляю с Праздником Весны!!

Answer (score 1):

> ...как все-таки правильно: "попятный"
> или "попятная"?

Употребляется и "на попятный" и "на попятную"  -- в значении *вспять,  назад.*

> А что такое этот самый "попятный"?

То же, что и в сочетании ***попятный двор***, т.е. *задний двор*, куда можно было отступить  "по трусости или слабости".

Нашёл в Нацкорпусе выражение ***попятный двор*** в его прямом значении:

> *Прикатились к дверям, а двери-то узеньки да низеньки; только ведь у нас
> не по-вашему, хоть тресни, а полезай:
> двери расступились, дровни вкатились и
> свалили пирог на дубовый стол, а сами
> тем же следом назад, **на попятный
> двор**, под навес, ― и опять все стало
> по-старому, по-бывалому.*
>
> [О. М. Сомов. Сказка о Никите
> Вдовиниче (1825-1833)]

Answer (score 0):

От "попятиться". Не убежать, а именно отступить, "попятиться" от своего решения, мнения, поступка и т.п. Пятками вперед. *На попятный* и *на попятную* — говорят и так, и эдак.